# How to effectively replace color from a range?

Tags: gimp, mask, selections

GIMP provides a very handy way of replace or rather *Rotating* color from one range to another but rotating the range of black is rather hard from this. The Gray option is a bit hard in a way that it only does gray colors.
 For example to make effective layer masks that has got a big range of colors on the subject as well as the background, it would be very useful if you could replace a certain range(that is the amount of intensity of blackness that a color has) with a black or white. A lot of youtube videos have tutorials on how to remove backgrounds on an image but a lot of them already have some clear background that on saturating give a perfection isolation between complex objects like hair and the background.
Therefore, if we could replace a certain range of gray/black of colors with the desired white/black color(to a 100% of intensity) it would be perfect to create a perfect layer mask. Is rotating colors the way to do this or are there any other ways?(although GIMP having the "**color exchange**", it is very hard to control.)
for example, there are 256 shades of gray in an 8 bit image, but we've got to replace the shades of say 1 to 50 to white and the rest to black then how can we achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you add an example?

Comment: @Tobi, i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to replace a range of gray values (even very dark gray) with some color is to use *Color>Map>Gradient map*

But if you just want a mask, duplicate the layer, *Color>Desaturate* and then use the Threshold tool, or Brightness/Contrast for a smoother transition, or even the Levels or Curves tools.

Comment: could you please demonstrate this or perphaps point to a link that does?

Comment: @bzal This? Gradient map or Desaturate? Note that I'm just answering your title question, and I don't think this is a good way to create a selection mask to cutout something except in a few very simple cases.

Comment: for a case such as a person's hair was being blown out by the wind and the hair is not a typical color, desaturating and messing with curves, threshold and levels just doesn't give accurate enough results. Do we have to take manual solutions to this?

Comment: @bzal Selecting hair is always a hairy process:). This requires partial selection on many pixels... in case of high contrast with a uniform background, color-to-alpha can be attempted but even this requires luck. I heard that the most efficient way is to use the improved version of foreground selector tool (aka RGGJAN fork, AFAIK included in  the builds from at partha.com, and now part of 2.9).

Comment: ,but the photo I had has a background color same as the hair and has got some black hair also, so none of these work. Do you recommend to any tutorials?

Comment: @bzal if the color of the hair is the same as the background, then it is hopeless... if it is not, then what you can try to do it play with *Colors>Components>Channel mixer* to create a grayscale image that increases the difference between hairs and background. Typically, for brownish hair (ie, red+green) on a green background, R=-50 and G=+200...

Comment: really? is there no way so we don't have to manually cut out every pixel?

Comment: @bzal As I said, the foreground selector, but if you want a decent result on hairs, you have to use the enhanced one.

Comment: which one do you mean? enchanced one?

Comment: @bzal RGGJAN's fork if 2.8, or experimental 2.9

Comment: even though I wasn't here for a long time, I forgot one thing. I found just the example for the sort of image I was thinking of. Do you think it would be illegal to give a link in here?

Comment: @bzal No,, if that clears up things

Comment: I actually came I very late again, and I lost the link, I googled the image but couldn't find the one I was talking about. I apologize for this inconvenience, but I'll make a definite post collecting all the resources again; sometime. :-)